# C - scanf didn't stop for user input

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I want to get the user input for variable `L`, but the `scanf` function is not working, and the program will jump and print the next cost statement and exit if I try to input anything.
I am new to C, and hope can get some help here. Thanks. Code below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 int main()
 {
    float L = 0; // L is litre
    float gallon;
    gallon = 3.785 * L;
    char x[2] = {'u', 'd'}; // u is unleaded and d is diesel
    float cost;
    printf("Hello, welcome to PetrolUpHere!!\n");
    printf("Would u like unleaded or diesel fuel?");
    scanf("%s", &x[2]);
    printf("Enter the litre you want to fuel:");
    scanf("%.2f", &L); //SCANF NOT WORKING
    switch (x[2]) {
        case 'u':
            cost = 1.98 * gallon;
            printf("The cost is :%.2f ", cost);
            break;
        case 'd':
            cost = 1.29*gallon;
            printf("The cost is :%.2f ",cost);
            break;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: x is an array of 2 chars but you are treating it like a 2D array of chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

```
scanf("%s", &x[2]);
```

I imagine you wanted to read a string into the variable `x`. Instead, you're saying "read a string into memory 2 positions past where `x` points". In this case that memory will be out of bounds. You should do this, since you only care about one character:

```
char input;
scanf("%c", &input);
```

Your `switch` statement is similarly broken; `x[2]` is again out of bounds. Use `input` from the above code instead.

As others have pointed out, using `%.2f` is not what you want to do when reading in L. Use `%f` instead. Generally you should only do something like that with format specifiers when printing out variables, rather than reading them in. Eventually you won't be using `scanf` anyway, since it's not a particularly safe way of getting input.

Finally: it seems like your understanding of how C strings work is shaky at best. This is understandable, since this is a fairly confusing topic for anyone who hasn't worked in C before, and especially for novice programmers. Here's [one explanation](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html); I'm sure you can find many more, probably better ones if you look.

Comment: the problem is solve, thanks. But now the problem appear is the program cant calculate the cost and print the cost = 0.0000 only.Hope can get help.thank

Comment: Please make a new question for this new problem and include your updated code there.

Comment: "Eventually you won't be using scanf anyway...", what do you mean by that Chris

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems in this much of your code (at least):

```
char x[2] = {'u', 'd'};//u is unleaded and d is diesel
float cost;

printf("Hello, welcome to PetrolUpHere!!\n");
printf("Would u like unleaded or diesel fuel?");
scanf("%s", &x[2]);
printf("Enter the litre you want to fuel:");
scanf("%.2f", &L); //SCANF NOT WORKING

switch (x[2]) {
```

1. `x` is an array of 2 `char` which is initialized, but is not a null terminated string.
2. You use `scanf("%s", &x[2])`, which is reading a string into data that is not part of the array `x`.
3. You then dereference `x[2]` in the `switch` statement — again accessing data that is out of bounds.
4. You don't check either `scanf()` call to ensure it was able to scan a result.
5. You don't print what you read immediately after you read it.
6. The `.` in the `scanf()` format is not valid; use `"%f"` (you probably do not want to use `"%2f"` as that would limit you to two digits maximum).
7. You haven't actually said what you entered in response to the 'unleaded or diesel' question.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", &x[2]);`
Should be:
`scanf("%c", &x[2]);`

---

`scanf("%.2f", &L);`
Should be:
`scanf("%2f", &L);`

And you initialized gallon with '0.0',then your output will always be '0.0'.
Hope it works.